# Как получить все даннные, пришедшие с сервера в данном пакете?

Tags: qt, http

Посылаю запрос серверу - в ответ получаю 103029 байт ответа (это из программы отслеживающей пакеты информация).
Читаю их в своей программе:

```
connect(m_pReply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(_slotReplyReadyRead()));

void HTTPRequest::_slotReplyReadyRead() {
    QByteArray body = m_pReply->readAll();
}
```

Но почему-то вычитываются только первые 5262 байт (плюс-минус десяток) этого пакета. Куда пропали остальные?
Как вычитать весь полученный ответ от сервера?
(статус ответа `200` и после него приходит сигнал `finished()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызывайте readAll() как только получите сигнал finished(), а не readyRead()

Сигнал readyRead означает, что получена новая порция данных, но не обязательно все.

Comment: Не обязательно все, но нового сигнала readyRead() нет!  А вот как раз на финише - буфер уже пустой у reply-я, там ничего не прочитаешь вообще. У меня есть реализация скачивания большого файла - вот там постоянно в слоте radyRead он дописывается по мере поступления сигнала, пока не докачает до конца. Здесь - сигнал приходит только один раз.

Comment: @Mira а какой размер буфера http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#readBufferSize задан?

Comment: Я задавала этот параметр с 0, то есть неограниченный - это ничего не изменило

Comment: @Mira - http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#finished согласно этому описанию, буфер будет как раз содержать все что нужно к моменту вызова finished()

Обновите вопрос с текстом слота finished(), будем смотерть

Comment: Вы правы, на финише оказался весь ответ, у меня он сначала был пустой - так как переписывался в readyRead слоте, теперь данные все. Вопрос решен. На самом деле очень странно qt себя ведет, а если б это был не последний и единственный пакет?  Спасибо за помощь!